# Make border-bottom disappear on hover with pseudo

Tags: css

Make `border-bottom` disappear on hover.

`<a id="toggle" href="#modal0">living in New York,</a>`

```
#toggle {
transition: all .3s ease-out;
position: relative;
}

#toggle::after{
content:'';
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 0;    
left:0;
bottom: 4px;                    /* <- distance */
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;  
}

#toggle::after:hover{   
transition: all .3s ease-out;
border-bottom: solid transparent 1px
}
```

Changed pseudo hover as suggested

```
#toggle:hover::after{
border-bottom: 1px transparent #999; 
transition: all .3s ease-out; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position:relative` to `#toggle`. This will make the positioning of the ::after pseudo-element relative to the element's position.

**Edit**

Per the update, you need to switch the `::after` and the `:hover`, so `#toggle:hover::after`. That way it's "the after pseudo-element, of the `#toggle` when hovered".

Comment: @user2252219 Updated.

Comment: Hmm. I gave that a go but it didn't seem to take effect. I added to OP what I put in. :)

Comment: @user2252219 I think the issue might be the `transparent #999`. This is what appears to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3uap9bo6/

Comment: Gah! It's getting too late. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user2252219 Sure thing. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the display property of your a-element to `inline-block` and set the height property to something like 0.9em to move the bottom border closer, eg.

```
<a id="toggle" href="#modal0" style="display:inline-block;height:0.9em;">living in New York,</a>
```